# SQL query works in DBeaver but not in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, subquery, oracle-apex, sqlperformance, dbeaver

I built a query to get data from tables through some dblinks.

This is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
SELECT 
    MOVS.POLIZA,
    MOVS.CONTRATANTE,
    MOVS.SERIE,
    MOVS.FECHA,
    MOVS.ENDOSO,
    SUM(MOVS.PORCENTAJE) AS PORCENTAJE,
    SUM(MOVS.PRIMA) AS PRIMA,
    SUM(MOVS.COMISION) AS COMISION,
    SUM(MOVS.IVA) AS IVA,
    SUM(MOVS.ISR) AS ISR,
    SUM(MOVS.IVA_RET) AS IVA_RET,
    SUM(MOVS.RTP) AS RTP,
    SUM(MOVS.MONTO_NETO) AS MONTO_NETO
FROM (
        SELECT 
            NVL(MMN.EMISOR, SUBSTR(MOV.REFERENCIA,0, 4)) || ' ' || LTRIM(MOV.NUMPOL, '0') AS POLIZA, 
            PR.NOMBRE_CLIENTE@ACSELXDBLINK(POLIZA.CODCLI) AS CONTRATANTE,
            MOV.NUM_SERIE AS SERIE,
            MOV.FEC_CONTA AS FECHA,
            MOV.NUM_ENDOSO AS ENDOSO,
            DETMOV.PORC_COM AS PORCENTAJE,
            DETMOV.PMA_COBRO AS PRIMA,
            DETMOV.TOT_COM_L AS COMISION,
            DETMOV.IVA_AG_L AS IVA,
            DETMOV.ISR_AG_L AS ISR,
            DETMOV.RET_IVA_AG_L AS IVA_RET,
            DETMOV.IMP_CED_L AS RTP,
            DETMOV.MTO_NETO_L AS MONTO_NETO,
            AG.COD_INTER AS COD_INTER
        FROM 
            MOV_AGENTE@ADCOMDBLINK MOV
            LEFT JOIN MOV_MANUAL@ADCOMDBLINK MMN
                ON MOV.ID_MOV_MANUAL = MMN.ID_MOV_MANUAL,
            DET_MOV_AGENTE@ADCOMDBLINK DETMOV,
            AGENTE@ADCOMDBLINK AG,
            TIPO_MOV_AGENTE@ADCOMDBLINK TIPOMOV,
            POLIZA@ACSELXDBLINK POLIZA
        WHERE 
            :P3_CLICK_BUSCAR = 1 AND
            DETMOV.ID_MOV_AGTE = MOV.ID_MOV_AGTE AND 
            MOV.ID_AGENTE= AG.ID_AGENTE AND 
            MOV.COD_TIPO_MOV= TIPOMOV.COD_TIPO_MOV AND 
            TIPOMOV.COD_TIPO_MOV != '0308' AND 
            POLIZA.STSPOL = 'ACT' AND
            POLIZA.CODPROD = NVL(MMN.EMISOR, SUBSTR(MOV.REFERENCIA,0, 4)) AND 
            POLIZA.NUMPOL = LTRIM(LTRIM(MOV.NUMPOL, ' '), '0') AND 
            POLIZA.NUMREN = (SELECT MAX(PO.NUMREN)
                            FROM POLIZA@ACSELXDBLINK PO
                            WHERE PO.CODPROD = NVL(MMN.EMISOR, SUBSTR(MOV.REFERENCIA,0, 4))
                            AND PO.NUMPOL = MOV.NUMPOL) AND 
            (
                (:P3_TIPO_USUARIO = 'A' AND 
                    AG.COD_INTER = TO_NUMBER(:P3_CLAVE_AGENTE)
                ) OR 
                /*
                 * This breaks the query in Apex 
                 (:P3_TIPO_USUARIO = 'C' AND 
                    (AG.COD_INTER IN (
                        SELECT 
                            INTER.CODINTER
                        FROM
                            INTERMEDIARIO@ACSELXDBLINK INTER,
                            CELULA_EJECUTIVO@ACSELXDBLINK CELEJEC
                        WHERE 
                            (:P3_AGENTE_SEL IS NULL OR INTER.CODINTER = TO_NUMBER(:P3_AGENTE_SEL)) AND 
                            INTER.CODEJECUTIVOCUENTA = CELEJEC.CODEJECUTIVO AND
                            INSTR(:P3_CELULAS, CELEJEC.CODCELULA) > 0
                    ))
                ) OR */
                (:P3_TIPO_USUARIO = 'G' AND 
                    (:P3_AGENTE_SEL IS NULL OR AG.COD_INTER = TO_NUMBER(:P3_AGENTE_SEL))
                )
            ) AND 
            CASE 
                WHEN :P3_FECHAINICIO IS NOT NULL AND :P3_FECHAFIN IS NOT NULL THEN 
                    CASE WHEN MOV.FEC_CONTA BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P3_FECHAINICIO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:P3_FECHAFIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                WHEN :P3_FECHAINICIO IS NOT NULL AND :P3_FECHAFIN IS NULL THEN
                    CASE WHEN MOV.FEC_CONTA >= TO_DATE(:P3_FECHAINICIO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                WHEN :P3_FECHAINICIO IS NULL AND :P3_FECHAFIN IS NOT NULL THEN
                    CASE WHEN MOV.FEC_CONTA <= TO_DATE(:P3_FECHAFIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN MOV.FEC_CONTA BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') AND ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), 1) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            END = 1 AND
            CASE 
                WHEN :P3_POLIZA IS NOT NULL THEN 
                    CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(MOV.NUMPOL) = TO_NUMBER(:P3_POLIZA) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                ELSE
                    1
            END = 1 
    ) MOVS
GROUP BY MOVS.POLIZA, MOVS.CONTRATANTE, MOVS.SERIE, MOVS.FECHA, MOVS.ENDOSO
)        
WHERE MONTO_NETO != 0
```

I build my queries in DBeaver and test them from there.

I've commented part of the query in where clause to get it work on SQL Command in Oracle Apex, but in some cases I really need to validate those conditions.

If I run the query on SQL Command in Oracle Apex with those conditions uncommented it doesn't work, I'm not getting any data and the application just gets stuck.

But if I run the query with those conditions uncommented from DBeaver I get the expected data in less than 1 second.

In both cases all params are the same and I'm using P3_TIPO_USUARIO as 'G'.

I don't know why is this happening, maybe an issue with subqueries in Oracle Apex, I don't know.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

In properties, just below where you enter the where clause, there is a property called "Page Items to Submit"  Do you have your Page Items, i.e. P3_TIPO_USUARIO, P3_AGENETE_SEL, and the others listed there?  There is an icon on the end of the field you can use to select the names for the list so you can be sure they are spelled correctly, and they should be in capital letters in the list, and in your where clause.  If they are not in the Page Items to Submit list your query will not return results.

Comment: I'm running the query in SQL Workshop / SQL commands. I also have all of the requiered fields listed on 'Page Items' property.